# System disk booting slowly (service .device)

Tags: boot, partitioning, systemd, 20.10

I recently looked at `systemd-analyze blame` and saw, that some service called `dev-nvme0n1p3.device` boots for 12.206 seconds, so I ran the same command on my second laptop, where similar service lasted only for about half a second. Both laptops have SSD disks, so what makes this big difference and how should I make my laptop boot faster?

`/dev/nvme01p3` is my system partition (mounted as filesystem root) formatted as Ext4 and is 25 GB large and I have ubuntu 20.10 Groovy installed, if that makes some difference.

Thank you very much for your suggestions and please say everything simply, I am such a nooby user.

Comment: Are there any messages in /var/log/syslog about disk issues around the time of boot ?

Comment: I looked in the log and I do not think, that there is, but as I wrote, I am pretty nooby, so say, if I should send the log here. Thanks

Comment: I have another interesting information. I ran benchmark on both drives (on each computer) and my primary laptop ended with speed about 1,3 GB/s and the faster laptop ended with 520 MB/s, so it is for me even more obscure.